# Is it possible to use my own Python interpreter with Conda's OpenCV python library?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, conda, spack

I work on a Python project that in one place callse Julia's code, and in other uses OpenCV.

Unfortunately, [pyJulia](https://github.com/JuliaPy/pyjulia) prefers Python interpreter to be [dynamically linked to the `libpython`](https://pyjulia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#your-python-interpreter-is-statically-linked-to-libpython). (I know I can build a custom Julia system image, but I fear the build delays when I want to test a development version of my Julia code from Python.)

What has worked so far, is using [Spack](https://github.com/spack/spack) instead of Conda. Python built by Spack has a shared `libpython` and Spack's repository does include a recent `opencv`.

Unfortunately, contrary to Conda, Spack is designed around a paradigm of compiling everything, rather than downloading binaries. The installation time of `opencv` is well over 1 hour, which barely is acceptable for a one-off install in the development environment, but is dismayingly long to build a Docker image.

So I have a thought: maybe it is possible to integrate my own Python with the rest of the Conda ecosystem?

Comment: A similar issue with work-around was mentioned here: https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock/issues/222#issuecomment-436507431.  What do you mean by "integrate my own Python"?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full solution, but Spack does support [binary packages](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binary_caches.html), as well as [GitLab build pipelines](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipelines.html) to build them in parallel and keep them updated.  What it does not have (yet) is a public binary mirror, so that you could install these things very quickly from pre-existing builds.  That's in the works.

So, if you like the Spack approach, you *can* set up your own binary caches and automated builds for your dev environment.

I am not sure what the solution would be with Conda. You could make your own conda-forge packages, but I think if you deviate from the standard ones, you may end up reimplementing a *lot* of packages to support your use case.  On the other hand, they may accept patches to make your particular configuration work.

Comment: I didn't know about the binary caches, Spack rules (again)! That changes a lot how I will deploy stuff with spack in general!